# connecting with samba: privileges issues windows server

Tags: permission, smb, file-sharing

I am trying using samba to connect to a folder I own on a windows server.  I connect by typing:

```
smb://the_windows_server/home/my_folder
```

Which works for every server where I either connect directly to my folder (i.e. `smb://the_windows_server/my_folder`) or when I have read privileges on all the directories in the chain to my folder.  In the present instance

```
smb://the_windows_server/home/my_folder
```

I do *not* have read privileges for `the_windows_server/home/`. The upshot is that OSX mounts `the_windows_server/home`, which has a nice 'not accessible' icon, and I stuck outside the folder I own and I want access to.

I am on OS X 10.8.4, samba provided by the OS.  I know I could do something to the windows server, but I do not manage it and I know it will be a painful and drawn out process to sort out if I try the 'ask the IT guys to fix the windows server' approach.  I would like to explore possible solutions on my OS X side of the equation.

Comment: Is it a true file server, or just a shared drive on another machine? How are you authenticating your identity to the server? Is your Mac bound to a Domain Controller and using Active Directory to authenticate your account or does your system prompt you for server account credentials when you try to connect(i.e. a different user name and password than what you use to login to your machine).

Comment: No active directory, and it is a share drive on another machine (what difference would that make from a 'file server'?).  I authenticate as username:password, which are different than the ones I sue for my machine.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you are able to mount the folder via samba, but you can't read the upper folder within the share.

To access the folder you have access to you can go directly to the folder using the 'Go to Folder' option in Finder: Click 'Go' in the menu bar and choose 'Go to Folder':

[image: Go to Folder]

Or hit Command + Shift + G.

I assume your samba share is mounted as /Volumes/home/my_folder, so enter this path in the text box that shows up and hit enter. Finder should open a new window showing your folder within the share.

If your share is mounted on a different path you could check the folder /Volumes for its name, using the same method as described above.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the above deals with the fact that I have no permissions in `/myserver/home`, which contains `/myserver/home/mydir`, and in fact what you suggest does not work because I do not have the permission to do anything once `/myserver/home` is mounted